# ACE TAO 6.2.6 ACE_wrappers_vc11_static.sln

Tags: visual-studio-2012, static-libraries, wrapper, solution, ace

has anyone successfully built the ACE+TAO 6.2.6 as static libraries in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 in Windows?  I just downloaded the latest version (i.e. ACE+TAO 6.2.6) and realised the package has no longer provided the static solution files (e.g. ACE_wrappers_vc11_static.sln).  The only solution file is ACE_vc11.sln and it has contained too many projects.  I was hoping someone has had the static.sln handy for sharing, or could tell me steps in details.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that ACE doesn't ship the Visual Studio solutions for static configuration. The reason is that they are all together add a significant amount of files to the release package. You can easily create them using MPC by running the following command in the directory where you need them

```
$ACE_ROOT/bin/mwc.pl -type vc11 -static -name_modifier *_vc11_static -apply_project
```